# Error on migration: SQLite3::SQLException: no such table: main.users

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, sqlite, omniauth, omniauth-twitter

I'm still pretty new to the Rails world. I've been working on a skill at a time so I thought I'd give Omni-Auth twitter a crack. I've been reading through this tutorial on SitePoint:

[Rails Authentication with OAuth 2.0 and OmniAuth](http://www.sitepoint.com/rails-authentication-oauth-2-0-omniauth/)

I'm find up until the point where it has me create a user model and modify the migration file before running `rake db:migrate`. Here's my migration file based on those instructions:

```
class CreateUsers < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table :users do |t|
      t.string :provider, null: false
      t.string :uid, null: false
      t.string :name
      t.string :location
      t.string :image_url
      t.string :url
      add_index :users, :providers
      add_index :users, :uid
      add_index :users, [:provider, :uid], unique: true

      t.timestamps null: false
    end
  end
end
```

But when I run `rake db:migrate` it throws this error:

```
SQLite3::SQLException: no such table: main.users: CREATE  INDEX "index_users_on_providers" ON "users" ("providers")/Users/jrshafer/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/sqlite3-1.3.11/lib/sqlite3/database.rb:91:in `initialize'
```

Any help you could provide this aspiring developer would be much appreciated.

You can view the full repo here: 
[kronoTweeter GitHub Repo](https://github.com/InsomniaNoir/kronoTweeter)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should create your table in one block and then add the indexes. But in your current code, you are trying to add the indexes in the same `create_table` block.

Try replacing your current code with this piece of code:

```
class CreateUsers < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table :users do |t|
      t.string :provider, null: false
      t.string :uid, null: false
      t.string :name
      t.string :location
      t.string :image_url
      t.string :url
      t.timestamps null: false
    end # you have to end the create_table block here

    # then you have to have the add_index statements
    add_index :users, :providers
    add_index :users, :uid
    add_index :users, [:provider, :uid], unique: true
  end
end
```

Then run:

```
bundle exec rake db:migrate
```

This should fix your problem.

Comment: this is the answer should be